# How to remove style.css on specific wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress with a child theme where in place where is wp_head(); `style.css` is added like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href='http://something' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Id like to remove this style on specific page (lets say this page has ID=5).
I've found how to do this in jQuery but it seems like a bad idea to remove styles client-side.

How can I remove this style via php? possibly using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style but only on one specific page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your WP Theme Functions.php file. It should de-queue style files from specific pages:

```
 add_action('init','_remove_style');

 function _remove_style(){
    global $post;
    $pageID = array('20','30', '420');//Mention the page id where you do not wish to include that script

    if(in_array($post->ID, $pageID)) {
      wp_dequeue_style('style.css'); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: How do you know what the default style sheet is called? I've tired everything and can't remove it

Answer (score 0):

In theme **functions.php** you can use page id condition and put it inside it.

```
global $post;
if($post->ID == '20'){
      // dequeue code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_page()` function inside `if` condition to target only specific pages

`is_page()` function takes any one of the following as parameters

- **ID** *(Ex: `is_page(5)`)*
- **Page Name** *(Ex: `is_page('Contact Us')`)*
- **Page Slug** *(Ex: `is_page('contact-us')`)*

**Examples**

```
if(is_page(5)){
// wp_dequeue_style
}


if(is_page('Contact us')){
// wp_dequeue_style
}


if(is_page('contact-us')){
// wp_dequeue_style
}
```